# How to throw the last exception from Polly after the final retry of HttpClient's SendAsync

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, polly

Requirement: Polly should throw the actual exception (from the downstream system) after the final retry failure while using `HttpClient`'s `SendAsync` method.

Currently, I always get `TaskCancelledException` after the final retry, I want the actual exception from the downstream endpoint after final retry failure.

My HttpClient registration:

```
AddPollyPolicies(services, configuration);
services.AddHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient((sp, options) =>
    {
        var httpClientOptions = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<TClientOptions>>().Value;
        options.BaseAddress = new Uri(httpClientOptions.BaseAddress);
        // Overall timeout of http client including all polly retries
        options.Timeout =
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(httpClientOptions.OverallHttpClientTimeoutInMilliSeconds);
    })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<OutboundRequestTimingDelegatingHandler>()
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(x => new DefaultHttpClientHandler())
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<CorrelationIdDelegatingHandler>()
    .AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry(PolicyName.HttpRetry);
```

My PolicyRegistry registration:

```
private static void AddPollyPolicies(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var section = configuration.GetSection(PoliciesConfigurationSectionName);
    services.Configure<PolicyOptions>(configuration);
    var policyOptions = section.Get<PolicyOptions>();

    var registry = new PolicyRegistry
    {
        {
            PolicyName.HttpRetry, RetryPolicyAsync(policyOptions.HttpRetry.MedianFirstRetryDelayInMilliSec,
                policyOptions.HttpRetry.RetryCount)
        }
    };

    services.AddPolicyRegistry(registry);
}
```

My retry policy:

```
private static AsyncRetryPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> RetryPolicyAsync(int medianFirstRetryDelayInMilliSec, int retryCount)
{
    //Retry delay algorithm - DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2 - https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry#wait-and-retry-with-jittered-back-off
    var delay = Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(medianFirstRetryDelay:
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(medianFirstRetryDelayInMilliSec), retryCount: retryCount);

    // Retry policy
    var waitAndRetryPolicy = Policy
        .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
        .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => HttpStatusCodesWorthRetrying.ContainsKey(r.StatusCode))
        .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(delay, (result, span, count, ctx) =>
            Console.WriteLine($"Retrying count is ({count})..."));


    return waitAndRetryPolicy;
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How big is your `OverallHttpClientTimeoutInMilliSeconds` setting? It seems that your HttpClient "global" timeout short-cuts your resilient strategy.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the default way Polly handles exceptions, any and all final failures should behave that way.

Please refer to the documentation, as well as their [unit tests](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/7c5ecfcfc7abceb33b19bcd8a2d252bd59a3df91/src/Polly.SharedSpecs/Retry/WaitAndRetryAsyncSpecs.cs#L117-L131)